# C# / Dotnet importing classes syntax

Tags: .net, c#-6.0

does someone know if this way of import classes in C# is correct?
[Code example of importing]

[image: 1]

Btw my issue was "Ambiguous reference", I resolved with this

```
using PathString = Microsoft.Owin.PathString;

            OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
            {
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                Provider = new OAuthAppProvider(),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(2),
                AllowInsecureHttp = true
            };
```

Comment: [Do not post screenshots of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: thanks for your comment, i will be careful with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common practice is to have a using statement at the top of your class, in your case

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
public MyClass
{
    public void someMethod()
    {
        var endPointString = new PathString("/token");
    }
}
```

In cases, when you have multiple namespace having same class name, then we use full namespace to access the class.

Comment: What about if I have this message? 

'PathString' is an ambiguous reference between 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.PathString' and 'Microsoft.Owin.PathString' [OwinSample]csharp(CS0104)

Comment: Then, what you've written is correct.